# Could not resolve org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0

Tags: java, gradle, telegram, telegram-bot

i am trying to create a sample project for telegram bot in java gradle.
i created a new project in java and add telegram dependency from 
telegram bot home page "https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api"

```
  plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'demo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0"
}
```

but when i run `./gradlew build` its saying

```
Could not resolve org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0.
     > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/telegram/telegrambots/4.4.0/telegrambots-4.4.0.pom
        > Could not find org.telegram:Bots:4.4.0.
          Searched in the following locations:
            - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/telegram/Bots/4.4.0/Bots-4.4.0.pom
            - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/telegram/Bots/4.4.0/Bots-4.4.0.jar
            - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/telegram/Bots/4.4.0/Bots-4.4.0.pom
            - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/telegram/Bots/4.4.0/Bots-4.4.0.jar
  > Could not resolve org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0.
     > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/telegram/telegrambots/4.4.0/telegrambots-4.4.0.pom
        > Could not find org.telegram:Bots:4.4.0.
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output says that `org.telegram.Bots:4.4.0` is not found. It's the parent pom of `org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0`.

If you look at [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/Bots) you will notice that only `4.4.0.1` is available - 4.4.0 is missing and that's what gradle complains about.

I didn't check jcenter, but I guess it's missing there as well.

**Solution:**

Use `org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0.1` instead of `4.4.0`. I didn't check the changelog, but if the author follows at least a basic versioning strategy this won't break anything.